# Why is Python printing strings so slowly?

Tags: python, printing

Say I have this code:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(1000):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+'\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

I would expect it to print 0-999 in one line and I would be able to see each and every number. But in fact Python would refresh ever so slowly (seemingly 5Hz), the result would jump from 5 to 17 to 87 to 99, etc.

Is there a way that I can print instantly in one line? I'm using Pycharm, and I tried Python's stock IDLE and it simply won't work. It wouldn't even print in one line.

Answer (score 1):

This will print every number:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(1000):
    print(str(i) , '\r', end='')
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

This will print each number on a "New Line"

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(1000):
    print(str(i)+'\r')
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

If you want to print all of the numbers on the same line separated by a space (wont display until the "end" of the loop):

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(1000):
    print(str(i), " ", end = ''),
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

To print a "Status Line" use:

```
from time import sleep
import sys

for i in range(21):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: I'm asking this question because I want to do a status line. So information must but printed within one line. Also thank you for sharing your code. I tried your code and the result looked like this: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98

Comment: I updated my answer... Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Aw that status bar is cute, but what I meant was like: this programme scans your whole hard drive. And the status bar would show which file it's currently on. I want that status bar to refresh real quick so that the user wouldn't really be able to see exactly which file that is because it's soooooo fast

Comment: I have updated my answer to include what you are asking for I believe....